# How to cast select union to decimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT FileStatusID
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].[TBL_FileStatus]
        WHERE IsActive = 1 AND (((@p_valuemin BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue) AND MaxValue <> @p_valuemin)
        OR ((@p_valuemax BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue) AND MinValue <> @p_valuemax))
        UNION
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].[TBL_FileStatus]
        WHERE IsActive = 1 AND (((MinValue BETWEEN @p_valuemin AND @p_valuemax) AND MinValue <> @p_valuemax)
        OR ((MaxValue BETWEEN @p_valuemin AND @p_valuemax) AND MaxValue <> @p_valuemin)
    )) TS
```

i have this code that return an int type ( List if int or number), but i want the return type to be DECIMAL. how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `CAST` or `TRY_PARSE` for same. But before applying `cast` you may check whether value is numeric or not by using `IsNumeric'.

For SQL Server 2012 and above

```
declare @que nvarchar(100) = 'xvzd21212.121'

SELECT TRY_PARSE(FileStatusID as decimal(18,2)) as FileStatusID
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].[TBL_FileStatus]
        WHERE IsActive = 1 AND (((@p_valuemin BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue) AND MaxValue <> @p_valuemin)
        OR ((@p_valuemax BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue) AND MinValue <> @p_valuemax))
        UNION
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].[TBL_FileStatus]
        WHERE IsActive = 1 AND (((MinValue BETWEEN @p_valuemin AND @p_valuemax) AND MinValue <> @p_valuemax)
        OR ((MaxValue BETWEEN @p_valuemin AND @p_valuemax) AND MaxValue <> @p_valuemin)
    )) TS
```

For before SQL server 2012

```
SELECT case when Isnumeric(FileStatusID) = 1 then cast(insull(FileStatusID,0) as decimal(18,2)) else 0 end as FileStatusID
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].[TBL_FileStatus]
        WHERE IsActive = 1 AND (((@p_valuemin BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue) AND MaxValue <> @p_valuemin)
        OR ((@p_valuemax BETWEEN MinValue AND MaxValue) AND MinValue <> @p_valuemax))
        UNION
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].[TBL_FileStatus]
        WHERE IsActive = 1 AND (((MinValue BETWEEN @p_valuemin AND @p_valuemax) AND MinValue <> @p_valuemax)
        OR ((MaxValue BETWEEN @p_valuemin AND @p_valuemax) AND MaxValue <> @p_valuemin)
    )) TS
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to convert to a decimal type value to a spesific precision :

`select convert(decimal(10,4), FileStatusID) as Decimal_Value`

in this case, the above query returns a value in the format `[FileStatusID].0000`